# How to use bootstrap datetime picker in angular8

Tags: jquery, angular, datetimepicker

i am using bootstrap datetime picker calendar, but i am not able to see the calendar but it was taking date and time in that input field. I am not able to find where i am going wrong. Can anyone help me please.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqndus?file=src%2Findex.html)

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group"  (click)="calendar()">
              <label for="">Inactive Date</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" formControlName="inactiveDate"
                name="inactiveDate" id='datetimepicker1'>
            </div>
          </div>
```

TS:

```
  calendar() {
    $(function() {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
  }
```

Comment: You code uses `jQuery`. Your demo has no `jQuery` dependency.

Comment: You can use bootstrap implementation for angular, example https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: Hi, i need date time picker calendar only, with am/pm